# Send message to SignalR hub from any Xamarin (Visual Studio 2017) android activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, signalr, signalr.client

I've been able to create and receive messages from a SignalR hub from a html page, aspx page and an Xamarin client which is the app I really need it for using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client v2.4.1 using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.  Once my Xamarin app authenticates the user I start the connection to the hub, next I wire up an event to receive messages.  All of this works just fine and I can receive messages in the android app no matter what activity is the current activity thanks to the event that is wired up.  Now that I have this working I want to be able to send a message from the client to the hub without creating another connection to the hub.  I've looked at static classes, but cannot get that to work.  My code is:

This is the code that is executed after the user is authenticated:

```
// Start SignalR connection
Client client = new Client(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username);

await client.Connect();

// Wire up the message received event
client.OnMessageReceived += (sender2, message) => RunOnUiThread(() => showMessage(message));
```

From here the user can navigate from view to view and is able to receive messages from the hub via the event and the `showMessage` method.  This all works flawlessly.

My Client Code:
This code was copied from a stack overflow working example, I modified it to my requirements.

```
namespace ChatClient.Shared
{
    class Client
    {
        private readonly string _platform;
        private readonly HubConnection _connection;
        private readonly IHubProxy _proxy;

        public event EventHandler<string> OnMessageReceived;

        public Client(string platform, string username)
        {
            string _username = "username=" + username;
            _platform = platform;
            _connection = new HubConnection("https://Example.com/SignalRhub", _username);
            _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("chathub");
        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {

            await _connection.Start();                 _proxy.On("broadcastMessage", (string platform, string message) =>
            {
                if (OnMessageReceived != null)
                    OnMessageReceived(this, string.Format("{0}: {1}", platform, message));
            });

            Send("Connected");
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> ConnectedUsers()
        {

            List<string> Users = await _proxy.Invoke<List<string>>("getConnectedUsers");

            return Users;
        }

        public Task Send(string message)
        {
            return _proxy.Invoke("Send", _platform, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I need to do is send a message to the hub using the connection created just after the logon to be distributed to all connected users.  I cannot figure out how to do that, I've tried using a static class and attempted to use methods I've found on the web, but nothing seems to work.

My Hub code:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    private static readonly List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        string userName = Context.QueryString["username"];
        string firstname = Context.QueryString["firstname"];
        string lastname = Context.QueryString["lastname"];
        string connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;

        var user = new User();
        user.Name = userName;
        user.ConnectionIds = connectionId;


        try
        {
            Users.Add(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }

        // send list of connected users to client as a test
        Send("Welcome " + userName, "Connected users are:");

        foreach (var display in Users)
        {
            Send("",display.Name.ToString());

        }

        // test sending to a specific user
        SendOne(connectionId, userName, "This is to a specific user.");

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopped)
    {

        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        var item = Users.Find(x => x.ConnectionIds == connectionId);

        Send(item.Name , " disconnected.");

        Users.Remove(item);


        return base.OnDisconnected(true);
    }

    public void SendOne(string connectionId, string userName, string message)
    {

        Clients.Client(connectionId).broadcastMessage(userName, message);

    }

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public List<string> getConnectedUsers()
    {
        List<string> UserNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var ConnectedUser in Users)
        {
            UserNames.Add(ConnectedUser.Name );
        }
       return UserNames;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of other things I will be doing in the hub, but for now I need to get the client to send messages without creating another connection

Is there a way I can access the connection created after the user is authenticated in other views/activities?

*** Update ***

I changed my code in accordance with Leo Zhu's answer below, however I get an error when I try to instantiate the class on the line:

```
Client client = new Client.GetInstance(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username);
```

`GetInstance does not exist` when it actually does.  No idea why it isn't "found".

*** Update ***

Removed the `new` keyword from the line:

```
Client client = new Client.GetInstance(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username);
```

It now reads:

```
Client client = Client.GetInstance(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username);
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try the singleton pattern,for example (Just to provide ideas，you need to code to your own needs):

```
public sealed class Client
  {
    // A private constructor to restrict the object creation from outside
    private Client()
     {
      ...
     }
    // A private static instance of the same class
    private static Client instance = null;
    public static Client GetInstance()
      {
       // create the instance only if the instance is null
       if (instance == null)
         {
           instance = new Client();
         }
       // Otherwise return the already existing instance
      return instance;
      }

  }
```

then you could call by `Client.GetInstance();`

Comment: I get an error, `The type or namespace name Singleton could not be found`.

Comment: Now I get an error on this line `Client client = new Client.GetInstance(MyUser.Firstname + " " + MyUser.Lastname, MyUser.Username);`, GetInstance does not exist ....

Comment: you could only refer to the code above，you should custom by your own need，i will talk it tomorrow，now i am outside！

Comment: The only difference between your code and mine is the parameters in `GetInstance`, yours have no parameters, mine does.  Removing the parameters made no difference, same error.

Comment: you only should call by Client client = Client.GetInstance(parameters)；

Comment: That is exactly what I do ... still get same error `Type name 'Getinstance' does not exist in the type 'Client'`.

Comment: Ok, now I got it ... removed the `new` keyword ... that did it.